# near "=": syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER for line 36,41,50,55

Tags: verilog

I am writing a code where based on the input conditions certain sequence detector modules are evoked and based on their respective output, final system output is set.

I have tried assign operator ,but I think its wrong.
I have tried to change the identifier with output reg etc.
I used<= for the same lines.
I used always block for the whole code.
ERROR IN LINES WITH ****

```
module direction_detection(event1,event2,uni_or_bi_in,event_in,timer_in,
     clk,rst,axel_detect,direction_up,direction_down,axel_count);

  input  event1,event2,event_in,uni_or_bi_in,timer_in,clk,rst;
  output direction_up ,direction_down,axel_count;
  output reg axel_detect;

  reg ticker_ON,ticker_up,event1_pulse,event2_pulse,event1_pcounter,event2_pcounter;
  wire concat_events;
  wire reset,axel_sq_out;

  always @ ( posedge clk)
    begin 
      if(rst==1'b1)
        begin
          direction_up <= 0'b0;
          direction_down <= 0'b0;
          axel_count <= 0'b0;
          axel_detect <= 0'b0;
          reset <= 1'b1;
        end 
    end

  timer_delay t1(timer_in,clk,reset,ticker_up);
  pulse_detector p1 (event1,clk,event1_pulse,event1_pcounter);
  pulse_detector p2 (event2,clk,event2_pulse,event2_pcounter);

  assign concat_events = {event1_pulse,event2_pulse};

  if ( uni_or_bi_in ==1'b1)
    begin 
      sequence_detector_uniD sdu1( rst,clk,concat_events,axel_sq_out,direction_up,direction_down );
      if (axel_sq_out==1'b1 && (direction_up==1'b1 || direction_down==1'b1))
        begin
          axel_count=axel_count+1; //****
          reset =  (direction_up || direction_down);
        end
      else
        begin
          reset =~(direction_up || direction_down);  // ****
        end
    end
  else 
    begin
      sequence_detector_biD sdb1( rst,clk,event_in,event1_pulse,event2_pulse,axel_detect );
      if (axel_detect ==1'b1)
        begin
          axel_count=axel_count+1; // ****
          reset=1'b1;
        end
      else
        begin
           reset=1'b0; // ****
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke modules conditionally like that, or instantiate modules within an if-else  block that's not a generate statement. You'll have to instantiate all modules then conditionally use their output.

You can try something like the below, which at least compiles however probably has other problems you'll need to work through.

```
module direction_detection(
        event1,event2,uni_or_bi_in,event_in,timer_in,
        clk,rst,axel_detect,direction_up,direction_down,axel_count);

    input  event1,event2,event_in,uni_or_bi_in,timer_in,clk,rst;
    output reg direction_up ,direction_down,axel_count;
    output reg axel_detect;

    reg  ticker_ON,ticker_up,event1_pulse,event2_pulse,
         event1_pcounter,event2_pcounter;
    wire concat_events;
    reg  reset,axel_sq_out;

    timer_delay t1(timer_in,clk,reset,ticker_up);

    pulse_detector p1 (
        event1,clk,event1_pulse,event1_pcounter);

    pulse_detector p2 (
        event2,clk,event2_pulse,event2_pcounter);

    sequence_detector_uniD sdu1(
        rst,clk,concat_events,axel_sq_out,direction_up,direction_down);

    sequence_detector_biD sdb1(
        rst,clk,event_in,event1_pulse,event2_pulse,axel_detect);

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if(rst==1'b1)
        begin
            direction_up <= 0'b0;
            direction_down <= 0'b0;
            axel_count <= 0'b0;
            axel_detect <= 0'b0;
            reset <= 1'b1;
        end else begin
            if (uni_or_bi_in==1'b1)
            begin
                if (axel_sq_out==1'b1 && (direction_up==1'b1 || direction_down==1'b1))
                begin
                    axel_count <= axel_count+1;
                    reset <=  (direction_up || direction_down);
                end
                else
                begin
                    reset <= ~(direction_up || direction_down);
                end
            end
            else
            begin
                if (axel_detect==1'b1)
                begin
                    axel_count <= axel_count+1;
                    reset <= 1'b1;
                end
                else
                begin
                    reset <= 1'b0;
                end
            end
        end
    end

    assign concat_events = {event1_pulse,event2_pulse};

endmodule
```